# In sequelize.js, is it possible to un-nest the results of a query with nested includes?

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I want to be able to nest my includes in a query, but I wanted the results to be un-nested.

For example:

```
db.a.findAll({
    where: {id: id},
    include: [
        { model: db.b, include: [
            { model: db.c, include: [
                { model: db.d }
            ]}
        ]}
    ]
})
...
```

returns something like this:

```
[
    {
        a: {
            ...
            b: {
                ...
                c: {
                    ...
                    d: {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

but I want this:

```
[
    {
        a: {
            ...
            b: {
                ...
            },
            c: {
            ...
            },
            d: {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Is this possible without refactoring the models/tables?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do this, but it's not the most ideal way to do it. You can manually re-link the object like this:

```
db.a.findAll({
    where: {id: id},
    include: [
        { model: db.b, include: [
            { model: db.c, include: [
                { model: db.d }
            ]}
        ]}
    ]
}).then(function(a) {
    //you may need to iterate over an array
    a.setDataValue('d', a.b.c.d);
    a.b.c.setDataValue('d', null);
    a.setDataValue('c', a.b.c);
    a.b.setDataValue('c', null);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You just need one include and there you nest all the models that you need:

```
db.a.findAll({
    where: {id: id},
    include: [
        { 
            model: db.b
        },{
            model: db.c
        },{
            model: db.d
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: Yes, but a is not associated with c or d and can only link through them like:
a -> b -> c -> d

Comment: As far as I know is not possible because the include is a join between tables and If you don't have an association between models then the only options is like you did it first at least not in sequelize.js